# Regla CSS a elementos específicos

Tags: html, css

Me gustaria usar `display: flex` para poner un `justify-content`.

Pero de 4 elementos hijos que tengo hay uno que me gustaria omitir y tenerlo en otra linea.

Como veis en el codigo, me gustaria aplicar `justify-content: space-around;` solo a los íconos de redes sociales y no al párrafo con el copyright.

```html
<footer>
    <img src="../img/twitter.png">
    <img src="../img/instagram.png">
    <img src="../img/youtube.png">
    <p>© 2020 Dell</p>
</footer>
```

```css
 footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es la diferencia entre el título y el contenido: «Cómo evitar display:flex» y «Me gustaría usar display:flex» ¿Finalmente la idea es utilizarlo o no?

Comment: @Shaz la idea es usarlo pero que un elemento en concreo ignore esa regla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que necesitas que el display solo afecte a las imágenes pero no asi al párrafo entonces lo mas conveniente parece ser:

- Envuelve los 3 elementos `img` dentro de un `section`
- Aplicale el display flex al contenedor `section` en vez del footer como tal
- Mediante clases identifica a todos los elementos a modificar

Aclaraciones:

> Solo coloqué medidas en pixeles al elemento `img` para hacerlo mas notorio en la maquetación, pero este *detalle* dependerá enteramente del recurso multimedia que tu ingreses y de la medida que la maquetación real que hagas le otorgue.

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      .pie-pagina__contenedor-social{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      } 
      .pie-pagina__elemento {
        height: 120px;
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100px;
      }
      .pie-pagina__elemento-parrafo {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    
    <footer class="pie-pagina">
        <section class="pie-pagina__contenedor-social">
          <img class="pie-pagina__elemento" src="../img/twitter.png">
          <img class="pie-pagina__elemento" src="../img/instagram.png">
          <img class="pie-pagina__elemento" src="../img/youtube.png">
        </section>
          <p class="pie-pagina__elemento-parrafo">© 2020 Dell</p>
    </footer>
```

Visualmente esto será el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero de esa forma no se aplica el justify-content al footer si no a cada imagen si no me equivoco no? y de esa forma se me quedan los iconos de forma vertical https://gyazo.com/e8b81339851be94d046583c26b783229

Comment: @Jorge.montejo checa la actualización parece ser que esto es lo que buscas comentame

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma: Agregando clases a las `img` y en el css aplicarle el estilo con `footer.imagen`

```
    <footer>
        <img class="imagen" src="../img/twitter.png">
        <img class="imagen" src="../img/instagram.png">
        <img class="imagen" src="../img/youtube.png">
        <p>© 2020 Dell</p>
    </footer>
    <style>
     footer.imagen{
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    </style>
```

Referencias:

[Selectores de clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías envolver los elementos a los que les quieres aplicar el `justify-content` en un `section` o un `div` para así aplicarle el css a los hijos dentro de ese mismo contenedor. Así el CSS solo se aplicará a esos elementos, y no a los que se encuentren fuera.